# How do I write good codes about making function that counts vowels in a word?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function named `countVowels` that takes string as a parameter named `word` and returns the number of vowels in the word.

I came up with two solutions but I don't know if they are good solutions or not.

I guess I don't even know how to judge what 'good' code is.

My question is ...

1. What could be the problems of the solutions I came up with?
2. If they are not ideal, what are ideal codes in this case and why?

These solutions are what I came up with, but I don't know if they are good solutions or not.

I guess I don't even know how to judge what 'good' code is.

Can I get some code reviews on these ones? What could be the problems of the solutions I came up with?

*First solution*

```
function countVowels(word){
    let vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
    let index = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++){
            if (word[i] == vowels[j]){
                index += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
};
```

*Second solution*

```
function countVowels(word){
    let vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
    let index = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (vowels.includes(word[i])) {
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    return index;
};
```

Comment: The second solution is much easier to read

Comment: This is not on point for stack overflow in my opinion, what you are looking for is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree that a code review is off-topic for this site.  You're soliciting potentially very opinionated responses - especially since you explicitly say you don't even know how to define what "good code" is.  Examples of opinionated responses:   _As for the the variable you've called `index`, I think most people would call that `count` or `numVowels`.  Especially since the function isn't called "indexVowels" and you've also explicitly said that you want to return "the number of vowels in the word"._ or _"you should use .toLowerCase" so that you correctly count both upper- and lower-case vowels"_

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Oh there is another webpage for code reviews. I will ask this type of question on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Wyck I appreciate you giving the example. I will keep those points in the example in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer a regex replacement approach here:

```js
function countVowels(word) {
    return word.length - word.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, "").length;
}

var input = "peninsula";
var numVowels = countVowels(input);
console.log(input + " has " + numVowels + " vowels.");
```

Here we define the number of vowels in an input string as being the original length minus the length of the same input with all vowels removed.

Comment: You can use `word.match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0` instead.

Comment: Thank you. These answers are so simple. I gotta go learn regex now..haha

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is much easier to read and understand.

Here's another solution I can come up with, similar to your second solution but without the for loop:

```js
function countVowels(word) {
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const foundVowels = [...word].filter((char) => vowels.includes(char))
  return foundVowels.length
};

console.log(countVowels("peninsula"))
```

Comment: Awesome use of the spread operator on the iterable!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will learn more about spread operator and other methods you used.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function countVowels(word){
    return word.split("").filter(e=>/[aeiou]/.test(e)).length;
}
console.log(countVowels("peninsula"));
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the .filter() part but hopefully I will be able to understand it as I learn more.

Comment: @kjs29 Basically the filter function tests each element of an array with a boolean function. If the function returns false, the element is discarded.